# Can't replace Xfwm4 by Compiz

Tags: 18.04, compiz, xfce, window-manager, error-handling

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on XFCE with Xfwm4 and I want to change Xfwm4 by Compiz but I can't. When I do `compiz --replace`, there is an error:

`compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to load plugin: ccp`

Since there is an error, I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>c</kbd> and I have no wm so I do `xfwm4` in a terminal and I return on Xfwm4.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for the plugin by installing compiz-* but now it do this

`compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : ini
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : default`

And there is an infinity loading

If fixed the infity loading, my ~/.config folder was protected.

Now, when I do `compiz ---replace`, I have a segfault :/

`compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : ini
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : default
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)`